# Android Studio got bugged after a PC crash

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, project

Today I was using Android Studio and, while I was programming, my PC improperly shuted down. Now every project look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqzlz.png)

Can you guys help me fix that?
I really really hope that I have not lost all my projects...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you have backups of your projects in a safe place. Uninstalling AS shouldn't affect them, but it's always better to have a backup than not.

Then can try to uninstall Android Studio, clear its caches and remains, and install again.

Comment: Install AS on another computer, copy your projects there and check that. If they aren't, then as I said, reinstalling AS should help